# Laravel - ConvertEmptyStringsToNull messes up default value behaviour?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.3

I have the following form input which is a required field.

```
{!! Form::text('email_local_part', old('email_local_part') ? old('email_local_part') : strstr(Auth::user()->email, '@', true), ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

On page load I want to set a default value. However if user submits without entering any value i.e. deletes default value, then upon form validation when the form is re-displayed I end up back with the default value.

This is happening because of the ConvertEmptyStringsToNull middleware. When I comment this middleware out the behavior of default value is as expected.

How can I fix without disabling the ConvertEmptyStringsToNull middleware as it its needed to insert null values into nullable mysql foreign key columns.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the old() helper's default value parameter it works, e.g.:

```php
{!! Form::text('email_local_part', old('email_local_part', strstr(Auth::user()->email, '@', true)), ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

You can even use the Null Coalescing Operator (PHP7+) to add model data or default if it doesn't exist:

```php
old('attribute', $model->attribute ?? 'default value')
```

This works with valdations and model data, also with empty old input and the "new" ConvertEmptyStringsToNull middleware.